# Why data generator is unreasonably slow in this simple codes (python yield)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, yield

Let's say I have a simple data loader as below. It loads a pickle file of around 50MB. **One call takes ~39.5 ms.**

```
def loader(image_id):
    cache_path = os.path.join(CACHE_DIR, 'train', '{:05}.pickle')
    with open(cache_path.format(image_id), 'rb') as f:
        item = pickle.load(f)
        mask = item['contour']
    return mask

%timeit loader(0)
%timeit loader(200)

### --- output ----
### 39.4 ms ± 442 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
### 40.3 ms ± 733 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So, I created a generator, and this generator runs the above function. The batch size (# of iterations) is merely 3 here.

```
def data_generator(dataset, config, batch_size=1):
    b = 0  # batch item index
    image_index = -1

    while True:
        image_index = (image_index + 1) % 2000
        gt_mask = loader(image_index)

        b += 1
        if b >= batch_size:         # Batch full?
            inputs = []
            outputs = []
            yield inputs, outputs   # dummy return
            b = 0                   # start a new batch
```

However, the computation time varies a lot, and it reaches up to **4.6 seconds**. How can this happen?

```
train_generator = data_generator(dataset_train, config, batch_size=3)
%timeit inputs, outputs = next(train_generator)
%timeit inputs, outputs = next(train_generator)
%timeit inputs, outputs = next(train_generator)
%timeit inputs, outputs = next(train_generator)

### --- output ----
### 4.63 s ± 137 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
### 4.44 s ± 100 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
### 4.32 s ± 73.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
### 4.25 s ± 10.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

If it is caused by I/O commands, how to solve this?

Comment: You are loading something, thought about IO-bound? The bigger the file, the bigger the load time .... other then that - how should we possibly answer this if we do not know what exactly `model.load_image_gt` does and what data it operates on? for all I know there cold be a `time.sleep(random.getint(0,4))` in it .... at least provide enough context so this _is_ answerable. i.e. what kind of things are loaded, how big, .etc...

Comment: You need to profile your code. Check out `cProfile` in Python documentation.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yes, it has IO-bound. I modified the example codes. It is simple pickle file loading. Why is time so slow then?

Comment: Your first timing is loading the same file over and over, while the second one cycles through 2000 different files. You're probably hitting a cache every time for the first one.

Comment: Okay, however, (after restarting python,) with the first run of `import numpy as np; a = np.random.randint(0, 2000, 1)[0]; %timeit loader(a)` also gives me 39.1 ms and I do not understand why..

Comment: That timing is also loading the same file over and over.